# Dualizing Complexes

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a dualizing complex of a Noetherian graded algebra $A$ (not necessary commutative). For any $M\in D_c^b(A)$, there is a natural morphism 
$$
\theta: R\Gamma_m(M) \to RHom_{A^o}(RHom_A(M,R),R\Gamma_m(R))
$$
in $D^+(A)$. 
Notations and terminologies we refer to the paper [Dualizing complexex over noncommutative graded algebras, A. Yekutieli], in which the author show that $\theta$ is an isomorphism whenever $R$ is balanced. Nevertheless I wonder whether or not $\theta$ is an isomorphism for arbitrary $R$.

Concerning the natural morphism, one can take $M$ to be a left bounded complex of injective modules, and take $R$ to be a complex of bimodules which are injective over $A$ and $A^{op}$. Thus $\Gamma_m(R)$ is also a complex of bimodules which are injective ofer $A$ and $A^{op}$ because $A$ is Noetherian. The natural morphism $\theta$ is given by the following morphism:
$$
\Gamma_m(M) \to Hom_{A^{op}}(Hom_A(M,R),\Gamma_m(R)).
$$

Comment: Can you tell what the natural morphism is? Yekutieli is a little vague about it.

Comment: Take $R = A'$, the Matlis dual of $A$, and $M$ some torsionless module (if $A$ is a domain then take $M = A$, for example). In that case the cohomology of $R \Gamma_m(M)$ is concentrated in degree larger than $1$, while the other complex is just $M$, so they cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: In general $R=A'$ is not finitely generated and so it would not be a dualizing complex of $A$.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, thinking that by "an arbitrary" $R$ you ment an arbitrary complex, not an arbitrary _dualizing_ complex.

Answer (score 2):

For an arbitray dualizing complex (not necessary balanced), I am going to prove the following version of local duality theorem.  I will be grateful for any comments and corrections. Notations and concepts are refered to [Here](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~amyekut/publications/dual-com/dual-com.pdf).

> **Theorem:** Let $A$ be a connected graded Noetherian algebra, and let $R\in D(A^e)$ be a dualizing complex (not necessary balanced). Then for any $X\in D^b_{fg}(A)$, the natural morphism 
>   $$
> \theta: R\Gamma_{\mathfrak{m}} (X) \to R\text{Hom}_{A^o}(R\text{Hom}_A(X,R),R\Gamma_{\mathfrak{m}}(R))
> $$
>   is an isomorphism in $D(A)$.

Proof of the Theorem: Firestly choose an injective resolution $X\to I$ in $K^+(A)$, and also choose an injective resolution $R\to E$ in $K^+(A^e)$. Then one knows that $A^o$-modules occures in $\text{Hom}_A(A/A_{\geq n},E)$  and $\Gamma_\mathfrak{m}(E)$ are all injective.
So for any $n\geq 1$ we get a commutative diagram in $K(A)$: 
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{Hom}_A(A/A_{\geq n},I) & \xrightarrow{f_n} & \text{Hom}_{A^o}(\text{Hom}_A(I,E),\text{Hom}_A(A/A_{\geq n},E))\\
\downarrow_{p_n} &  & \downarrow_{q_n}\\
\Gamma_\mathfrak{m}(I) & \xrightarrow{g} & \text{Hom}_{A^o}(\text{Hom}_A(I,E),\Gamma_\mathfrak{m}(E)),
\end{array}
$$
where all $p_n,q_n,f_n,g$ are the canonical jomomorphisms of complexes.
Note that $\lim_{n\to \infty} p_n$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n$ are all quasi-isomorphisms. So to prove that $g$ is a quasi-isomorphism it quivalent to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n$ is a quasi-isomorphism.

Since $H^i(\text{Hom}_A(I,E))$ is finitely generated and vanishes when $|i|\gg0$, one can choose a resolution $P\xrightarrow{\sim} \text{Hom}_A(I,E)$ in $D(A^o)$ such that $P$ is bounded above and all $P_i$ are finitely generated pojective $A^o$-modules. Again we have a commutative diagram in $K(A)$:
\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{Hom}_{A^o}(\text{Hom}_A(I,E),\text{Hom}_A(A/A_{\geq n},E)) &\xrightarrow{u_n} & \text{Hom}_{A^o}(P,\text{Hom}_A(A/A_{\geq n},E))\\
\downarrow_{q_n} &  & \downarrow_{r_n}\\
\text{Hom}_{A^o}(\text{Hom}_A(I,E),\Gamma_\mathfrak{m}(E)) & \xrightarrow{v} & \text{Hom}_{A^o}(P,\Gamma_\mathfrak{m}(E)),
\end{array}
Where $r_n,u_n,v$ are the natural homomorphism of complexes.
Now note that $\lim_{n\to \infty} u_n$ and $v$ are quasi-isomorphisms. From the fact that $\text{Hom}_{A^o}(P,-)$ commutes with direct limits of complexes with a common lower lound, one obtains that $\lim_{n\to \infty} r_n$ is a quasi-isomorphism, and so is $\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n$ too. Therefore the cononical homomorphism $g$ is a quasi-isomorphism.

At last, the construction of $\theta$ tells that it is an isomorphism in $D^+(A)$.

Comment: In Yekutieli's article the fact that $\lim f_n$ is a quasi-isomorphism needs lemma 4.19, and this deppends strongly on the fact that $R$ is balanced. I don't see how you generalize this to the non-balanced case.

Comment: Lemma 4.19 only needs that $R$ is a dualizing complex which induces an equivalence of categories between $D_{fg}^b(A)$ and $D_{fg}^b(A^o)$.